# A compound WHERE clause in GAQL?

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ads-script

Could you please confirm GQAL doesn't support `compound WHERE clause`?

```
 FROM group_placement_view\
 WHERE\
    metrics.impressions >= 10000 \
    AND (metrics.video_view_rate < 10' OR metrics.average_cpm > 10000 )
```

and not event `OR` as non-compound clause?

```
    metrics.average_cpm\
 FROM group_placement_view\
 WHERE\
    metrics.impressions >= 10000 \
    OR metrics.video_view_rate < 10'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WHERE clause may only contain AND conditions https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/query/grammar

Answer (score 0):

OR for string fields can be simulated with REGEXP_MATCH. But in very this case using AND within 2-3 queries is the only way. GAQL is very flat QL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).